# Facebook Messenger Bot - Invalid URL button fields for List Template

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I have been working to send a list to user containing some data. I am following [facebook's doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/list) to setup my request payload. However, I am getting the following error:

```
{'error': {
    'message': '(#100) Invalid URL button fields provided. Please check documentation for details.', 
    'type': 'OAuthException', 
    'code': 100, 
     'error_subcode': 2018125, 'fbtrace_id': 'GZFFcM+j5e/'}}
```

Here is my JSON Payload:

```
{'recipient': {'id': 'MY_MESSENGER_ID'}, 
 'message':
    {'attachment': 
       {'type': 'template', 
        'payload': 
          {'template_type': 'list', 
           'top_element_style': 'compact', 
            'elements': 
                [{'title': 'Hello 1', 'subtitle': 'Subtitle 1', 
                 'buttons': 
                    [{'title': 'View', 'type': 'web_url', 
                      'url': 'https://www.medium.com/', 
                      'messenger_extensions': 'false', 
                      'webview_height_ratio': 'full',
                      'fallback_url': 'https://www.medium.com/'}],
                 'default_action': 
                    {'title': 'View', 'type': 'web_url', 
                    'url': 'https://www.medium.com/',
                    'messenger_extensions': 'false', 
                    'webview_height_ratio': 'full', 
                    'fallback_url': 'https://www.medium.com/'}}, 
              {'title': 'Hello 2', 'subtitle': 'Subtitle 2', 
               'image_url': 'https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/1*Vkf6A8Mb0wBoL3Fw1u0paA.jpeg', 
               'buttons': 
                      [{'title': 'View', 'type': 'web_url', 
                         'url': 'https://www.medium.com/',
                         'messenger_extensions': 'false', 
                         'webview_height_ratio': 'full', 
                         'fallback_url': 'https://www.medium.com/'}], 
               'default_action': 
                      {'title': 'View', 'type': 'web_url', 
                       'url': 'https://www.medium.com/', 
                       'messenger_extensions': 'false',
                       'webview_height_ratio': 'full', 
                       'fallback_url': 'https://www.medium.com/'}}]}}}}
```

I have checked, re-checked it multiple times. PLUS, I have sent the facebook's example json from the doc but I have got the same reply. Please take a look and let me know where I am stuck!

This is my end url:
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token="

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only `whitelisted_domains` allowed in button url fields. let me know if this solves?

Comment: I disabled messenger_extension to false. Whitelisted domain is only needed if it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request has two issues:

- For `default_action`, you can set `fallback_url` only if `messenger_extensions:true`
- `default_action` cannot have a `title` prop.

Try this:

`{
    "recipient": {
        "id": "{{PSID}}"
    },
    "message": {
        "attachment": {
            "type": "template",
            "payload": {
                "template_type": "list",
                "top_element_style": "compact",
                "elements": [{
                        "title": "Hello 1",
                        "subtitle": "Subtitle 1",
                        "buttons": [{
                            "title": "View",
                            "type": "web_url",
                            "url": "https://www.medium.com/",
                            "messenger_extensions": "false",
                            "webview_height_ratio": "full"
                        }],
                        "default_action": {
                            "type": "web_url",
                            "url": "https://www.medium.com/",
                            "messenger_extensions": "false",
                            "webview_height_ratio": "full"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Hello 2",
                        "subtitle": "Subtitle 2",
                        "image_url": "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/1*Vkf6A8Mb0wBoL3Fw1u0paA.jpeg",
                        "buttons": [{
                            "title": "View",
                            "type": "web_url",
                            "url": "https://www.medium.com/",
                            "messenger_extensions": "false",
                            "webview_height_ratio": "full"
                        }],
                        "default_action": {
                            "type": "web_url",
                            "url": "https://www.medium.com/",
                            "messenger_extensions": "false",
                            "webview_height_ratio": "full"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Happy to help =)